# How to plot table data in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a table output as follows.

```
             Friday Monday Saturday Sunday Thursday Tuesday Wednesday
Card         18167  18381    20068  18721    17604   18753     17826
Cash         13541  13100    13201  13510    13231   12865     13426
Discount     587    594      578    572      602     622       583
```

I want to plot this on a 3 bar chart. on x axis there will be Days listed and on y axis will be a card data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `?barplot`

```
barplot(tbl, beside=TRUE, legend = TRUE)
```

---

Or using `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
tbl %>%
   as.data.frame()  %>%
   ggplot(., aes(x= Var2, y = Freq)) + 
           geom_bar(aes(fill=Var1), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

#### data

```
tbl <- structure(c(18167L, 13541L, 587L, 18381L, 13100L, 594L, 20068L, 
13201L, 578L, 18721L, 13510L, 572L, 17604L, 13231L, 602L, 18753L, 
12865L, 622L, 17826L, 13426L, 583L), .Dim = c(3L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(
c("Card", "Cash", "Discount"), c("Friday", "Monday", "Saturday", 
"Sunday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday")), class = "table")
```

Comment: can we use ggplot2 in this case ? to make it interactive

Comment: Awesome. Thanks alot :)